# Continued fractions and class groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $d$ be a positive integer. It is well-known (due to Lagrange) that the continued fraction of $\sqrt{d}$ is eventually periodic. Moreover, it is known that the equation

$$\displaystyle x^2 - dy^2 = -1$$

is soluble in integers $x,y$ if and only if the continued fraction of $\sqrt{d}$ has odd period.

An alternative criterion is given in terms of the class group $\text{CL}(K_d)$ of $K_d = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and the *narrow class group* $\text{CL}^\sharp(K_d)$. The difference is that the former mods out all principal ideals, while the latter only mods out principal ideals of *positive norm*. Indeed, we see that the above equation, which exactly identifies when $\mathcal{O}_{K_d}$ has a unit of norm $-1$, implies that the two groups are equal. The converse is also true.

More precisely, we don't need to look at the entire class group/narrow class group, but only the $2^k$-torsion subgroups for $k = 1, 2, \cdots$. Indeed, we have the following alternative criterion: the equation $x^2 - dy^2 = -1$ is soluble in integers $x,y$ if and only if $\text{CL}(K_d)[2^k] \cong \text{CL}^\sharp(K_d)[2^k]$ for all $k \geq 1$ (note by the finiteness of the class group, both sides eventually stabize).

Is there deeper connection between continued fractions of $\sqrt{d}$ and the $2^k$-torsion criterion above?

For instance, we know that for all primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ the equation $x^2 - py^2 = -1$ is soluble, which means that for any such prime $\sqrt{p}$ always has odd period. Is there any reason why one should believe this looking only from the continued fraction side?